# Python 3 append array in float32?

Tags: python-3.x

When I loop through my data, a .csv file and assign values from each row to a array element // I need the values to be float32, how do I do that ?  this works, but they are not the type that I want ?  Basemap complains, Thanks!

```
csvReader = csv.reader(stores)
header = next(csvReader, None)
latIndex = header.index("lati")
lonIndex = header.index("long")

# Make an empty list
coordList = []

# Loop through the lines in the file and get each coordinate
for row in csvReader:
    lat = row[latIndex]
    lon = row[lonIndex]
    result = (lat, lon)
    coordList.append(result)    # how to make it float32 ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean numpy.float32 (There is nothing called that in vanilla python):

```
lat = numpy.float32(row[latIndex])
lon = numpy.float32(row[lonIndex])
```

Comment: Great thanks // super fast answer and my first ever post, I like this!! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Glad to help. Can you please mark the answer correct?

Comment: sorry for stupid question, new to this - how do I do that ?

Comment: Click the big check mark that appears to the left of the answer

Comment: Ahhhh, its grey color, so I didn't see it // this interface is a little bit wonky, but I won't complain since I am getting help, done.